# Excel Connect data points with line is DISABLED

Tags: excel, graph

I have a graph for a formatted table in Excel.

I have a classic issue with empty values that are reflected on graph as zero and the "Connect data points with line" option is disabled. I can't check it.

[image: Hidden and Empty Cells Settings]

I googled but never found the answer. Does anybody know why?

**UPDATE: SOLUTION:** After I added more columns for the graph and removed the heading column from the graph, the options "Gaps" and "Connected data points with line" became enabled.

Comment: If your data for the y-values is in B1:B30 (say) then in cell C1 type the formula `=IF(LEN(B1:B30)>0,B1:B30,na())` and then use column C for your y-values in the chart

Comment: Please refrain from asking non-programming questions here. This question is better suited for https://superuser.com/. Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about superuser.com. Will keep posting here just programming stuff. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: You should be ok on here, the brief says "or complex formula development" in it... Part of: 
Questions tagged [excel]

Only for questions on programming against Excel objects or files, or complex formula development. You may combine the Excel tag with VBA, VSTO, C#, VB.NET, PowerShell, OLE automation, and other programming related tags and questions if applicable. General help regarding Excel for single worksheet functions is available at Super User (http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got round something similar by duplicating the data series and replacing zero values with #NA, then my chart worked fine.

Not found that answer yet, but it is on here somewhere:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69077964/4961700)

Comment: It's hopefully on https://superuser.com/ since this question is not about programming :-)

Comment: @BigBen oh so **real** programmers don't use Excel?

Comment: No, they do, but this question is not about *programming*. It's about a chart. That is general Excel functionality and not on-topic here. The Excel tag says "only for questions about programming against Excel objects or files..."

Comment: @BigBen questions on here don't need to be about 5 or 5000 lines of code, but using functions and tricks to get data or charts to behave as needed.

Comment: Eh, no they don't. Read the tag again. This is a classic question for SuperUser.

Comment: @BigBen then you will be deleting several thousand incorrect questions that are on here about excel issues...

Comment: No they should be *migrated* to where they belong.

Comment: @BigBen Goood luck - will watch your progress with that task.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't know about superuser.com. Will keep posting here just programming questions. Thank you

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you. Unfortunately, it ignored for #NA for me, but your idea of copying the data lead me to some ideas of creating a formula for calculating automatic average data. Will continue with researching and asking on superuser.com

Comment: @AlexandrMeyer so did you use na() ?

Comment: @SolarMike . I guess I am doing something wrong, I added =NA() function, it generated #N/A text and graph keeps showing 0.

Comment: See this, and give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69077964/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you for your help. I believe in a similar situation it will help and I will vote and mark your comment as a solution.