# How to not display labels in pie chart that are 0%

Tags: excel, label, pie-chart

I have some data in excel that I want to graph in a pie chart (see image 1) where the text will be the labels and the numbers will turn into percentages. The problem is, when i go to graph the data, it shows the labels for ALL of the sections, even the ones that are 0% in the pie chart. So this really overtakes my entire chart.
I do not want to manually select the data as this is a dynamic spreadsheet and sections that are zero now may not be zero down the line.

Is there a way to tell excel to not at all display the labels for the sections that are 0%??

as you can see in the current graph (second image), there are way more labels than there are sections in the pie chart, and it looks extremely busy.

Thank you!

[image: data to graph]

[image: current graph]

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850339/4961700

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your data, so I will assume it is in column `B`, with category names in column `A`

Generate a new column with the following formula:

```
=IF(B2=0,"",A2)
```

[image]

Then right click on the labels and choose "Format Data Labels"

Check "Value From Cells", choosing the column with the formula and percentage of the Label Options.

Under `Label Options -> Number -> Category`, choose "Custom"

Under `Format Code`, enter the following:

```
0%;;
```

[image]

Result should look like this:

[image]

(labels selected so you can see there's a blank one)

Comment: @cybernetic.normad  all this seemed to do was remove the percentages from all the labels, even the ones that were >0%, and didn't delete any of the labels entirely

Comment: See the edit to my answer

Comment: unfortunately this just deleted the 0% from the pie chart, but the label with the category name still shows.....

Comment: I misunderstood your initial question, See new edit to my answer