# VBA for Dynamic Chart Data with N/A or Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I can define columns and data for required columns and So on for dynamin range

**But how do i convert it into complex charts in the excel file under Tab "Chart Data"**

Can anyone advise

```
Sub create_graph()

Dim ws  As Excel.Worksheet
Dim x As Range
Dim y As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chart Data")

Set x = ws.Range("B8:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
Set y = ws.Range("C8:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)

ws.Shapes.AddChart.Select
With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = x
  End With

End Sub
```

Now there are 2 questions here

- can i create a chart where i can ignore blanks and N/A so my data can
  alight better in Chart
- can you help me to with additional code to    create the image chart

Chart image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ElYu.jpg

Comment: To ignore blanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69077964/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike. I tried that.                                                                                            
Empty or #N/A cells are not plotted, but still takes up space on the time axis.
Tried changing 'Hidden and Empty Cell Settings, Does not work either as the chart is very complex. Can you help me create similar chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart is not so complex. But your data is not laid out optimally. The #N/A in the Y value columns will not plot points, but all the blanks in the date column are messing you up.

Delete all those rows below row 33. They are what is killing the chart.

Now select the range A7:R33, and on the Insert tab of the ribbon, choose Table. This converts the range into a Table, which is a data structure with advanced properties.

Make sure the chart uses the columns of the Table as its data.

When you add new data to the row below the Table, the Table notices and expands to include the added row. Formulas that reference a whole row of the Table will also expand to include the new row. This means the chart will expand to include the new data.

Here's a tutorial I wrote long ago about the magical dynamic nature of Tables: [Easy Dynamic Charts Using Lists or Tables](https://peltiertech.com/easy-dynamic-charts-lists-tables/).

Comment: Excellent , so simple and clear , tried it , works great !!!