# Not to show axis label if value is zero EXCEL

Tags: excel, graph, axis

Is there any way to not to show an axis label if value is zero against that?

Suppose if a table is like below

| Vehicles Sold per Brand | jun-21 | jul-21 | ago-21 | sept-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Opel | 2 | 4 | 3 | 5 |
| Renoult | 6 | 3 | 8 | 1 |
| Ferrari | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Mercedes | 1 | 1 | 6 | 4 |
| Seat | 2 | 0 | 4 | 2 |
| Others | 12 | 11 | 15 | 16 |

**If i want to not to get the graph of Ferrari in axis, what should I do?**

[image]

I know that, I can hide that column if the graph is not to be shown for that. I can not use that since its a highly dynamic data and I dont want to go and hide it everytime.

Could somebody help?

Many thanks an advance

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69077964/4961700

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I really appreciate but the issues looks different to me @SolarMike

Comment: Did you make the effort to test?

Comment: Yes, I did and I didn't work out. @SolarMike

Comment: Any idea? I'm stuck and I've been trying a lot of things since yesterday but none of them worked out.  I would be tremendously grateful if you could help @SolarMike

Comment: So make the Ferrari row NA() based on a choice - much like the example I showed you except row instead of column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, quick and dirty:

[image]

But I would then produce the table of numbers so that any row not to be included gets removed and then build the chart with 5 only and not have the gap. I will let you work on that.

So, did that as well, but I will let you figure out how to control the Legend:
[image]

The trick is to use large(), but you may need to be wrapping with if() to control 0 better...

Comment: The solution is fantastic but how would you generate the names for column A?

Comment: @Max The two formulae shown do that - they are set to do column A then as the relative addressing is set, you just drag right. Did that so it was easy to build the block of formulae...

Comment: But if Ferrari has in June the value 2 (for example) it will not be appearing