# Stacked Column Chart with Different Dates

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-charts

I'm looking for Stacked Column Bars on each date that are present in the given data but not as a whole, so I needed dates on the x-axis with their corresponding count on the y-axis.

**Screenshot 2 is what I am actually looking for inside my Excel File. How can I correct my chart ?**

Secondly is there any way to add a Total Sum Data Label on each Stacked Column Bar in Millions?

**Screenshot 1:**
[Excel File Screen View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FNYE.jpg)

**Screenshot 2:**
[Expected Result View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHaWr.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps you might find some hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71870957/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike That is a different issue.