# Excel graphs: change data range while keeping all the formatting

Tags: excel, graph, formatting

Can you somehow keep the formatting (marker color, line type, x-axis values) while changing the data range/series for input for an excel table? By default it seems to regress to blue lines in standard formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I would select the data line in the graph and in the formula bar directly change the range for the y values.

Or, if I wanted the change to be "easier" I would edit the data in the range of cells used for the y values on the sheet.

You might find this answer I did a while back useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71870957/4961700