# Excel graph is not accepting named range for values

Tags: excel, graph, dynamic, range, named

I have created dynamic named ranges for sections of a table. I normally can use these in a graph by setting the values to the named range, i.e. Sheet1=MyRange.
But it is not working, it keeps saying that the reference is not valid.  I have tried an existing graph and created a new graph.

Data is up to 10 rows and up to 25 columns but changes. It may be 5 rows and 10 columns, or 10 rows and 25 columns, etc...
It is simple data, text in rows, and numeric values in columns. I am using Excel 365.

Here is basically what the data looks like...
[image]

Here are the definitions of the named ranges...

[image]

So it is Legend values = Sheet1!LegendNames, takes in first two columns
Values = Sheet1!ValueCols, takes in columns with numbers.  The Yrs I have left off for now as I could not get this simple thing to work.  Anywhere you look online (and I have done it before), says to just set the data source to the worksheet name and the named range, as above.

Comment: Without any example none of us can guess what possible error you have, but have a look here, and give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71870957/4961700

Comment: Okay the offset didn't show up....it is =OFFSET('Sheet1'!$H$25,0,0,COUNTIF('Sheet1'!$F$25:$F$34,"<>No Data"),MATCH("Grand Total",'Sheet1'!$H$23:INDEX('Sheet1'!$23:$23,1,COUNTA('Sheet1'!$23:$23)))-1)