# Create a bar chart for a dataset/range that has blanks in it?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I need to create a bar chart on excel for the data (see picture attached), as you can see there are blank cells in the dataset. I don't want to manually select the cells which have data in them and press "insert" then select the chart, is there any way to use VBA for this ?

Thanks

DATASET

[image]

Tried Selecting the entire row using vba then creating chart, then trying to remove the blank data on the chart it self but it didn't work

Comment: Then try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69077964/4961700