# Creating a graph each time I change a drop down list value

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried writing a code where each time I change values of like 7 drop down lists, it would create a new line chart, but when I store it into a Command button and activate it, it says "Wrong Number of arguments or invalid property assignment". I am quite new to VBA, so sorry for any inconvenience caused.

```
Sub CreateDynamicChart()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Dim chartRange As Range
    Dim dropDown As Shape
    Dim dropDownRange As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace with your sheet name
    
    ' Set the range of the master table for the chart
    Set chartRange = ws.Range("A1:H10") ' Replace with your master table range
    
    ' Create a new chart object
    Set chartObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=400, Height:=300)
    
    ' Set the chart source data
    chartObj.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=chartRange
    
    ' Set the drop-down lists and their associated ranges
    Set dropDown = ws.Shapes("DropDown1") ' Replace with your drop-down list shape names
    
    Set dropDownRange = ws.Range("A1:A10") ' Replace with the range for the first drop-down list
    
    ' Add a change event for each drop-down list
    With dropDown.OLEFormat.Object
        With .Object
            .OnAction = "UpdateChart"
            .LinkedCell = dropDownRange.Cells(1).Address
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Repeat the above block for each of the other six drop-down lists, modifying the drop-down shape and range
    
    ' Call the UpdateChart procedure to create the initial chart
    UpdateChart
End Sub

Sub UpdateChart()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Dim chartRange As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace with your sheet name
    
    ' Set the range of the master table for the chart
    Set chartRange = ws.Range("A1:H10") ' Replace with your master table range
    
    ' Clear existing chart
    For Each chartObj In ws.ChartObjects
        chartObj.Delete
    Next chartObj
    
    ' Create a new chart object
    Set chartObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=400, Height:=300)
    
    ' Set the chart source data based on the selected values from the drop-down lists
    ' Modify the below lines to reference the correct drop-down lists and ranges
    
    Dim selectedValue1 As String
    Dim selectedValue2 As String
    ' ...
    Dim selectedValue7 As String
    
    selectedValue1 = ws.Range("A1").Value
    selectedValue2 = ws.Range("A2").Value
    ' ...
    selectedValue7 = ws.Range("A7").Value
    
    ' Create the dynamic range for the chart based on the selected values
    Dim dynamicRange As Range
    Set dynamicRange = chartRange.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1).Find(selectedValue1).Offset(, 1)
    
    For i = 2 To 7
        Set dynamicRange = Intersect(dynamicRange.EntireRow, chartRange.Columns(i)).Find(selectedValue1).Offset(, 1)
    Next i
    
    ' Set the chart source data
    chartObj.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=dynamicRange
    
    ' Format the chart as desired
    
End Sub
```

Tried Using this code, but just comes up with the error.

Comment: Use the F8 key to step through the code line-by-line; which line does the error appear on? Which line/s aren't doing what you expect?

Comment: Have you investigated Pivot Charts? All this is built in with no code required.

Comment: Perhaps the data ranges for the charts can be controlled by the drop downs; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69077964/4961700